# Not able to Copy wwwroot/lib/jQuery/bower.json and some other json, js and css files

Tags: docker, azure-devops, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to containerize Asp.Net Core 3.1 MVC application. Docker file is working fine locally but when trying to build image through step in Azure Pipeline it is throwing error

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.426/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(147,5):
> warning MSB3026: Could not copy
> "/source/SampleWebApp/wwwroot/lib/jQuery/bower.json" to
> "/app/wwwroot/lib/jQuery/bower.json". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms.
> Could not find a part of the path
> '/app/wwwroot/lib/jQuery/bower.json'.
> [/source/SampleWebApp/SampleWebApp.csproj]
>
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.426/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(147,5):
> warning MSB3026: Could not copy
> "/source/SampleWebApp/wwwroot/lib/jQuery/src/core/camelCase.js" to
> "/app/wwwroot/lib/jQuery/src/core/camelCase.js". Beginning retry 1 in
> 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path
> '/app/wwwroot/lib/jQuery/src/core/camelCase.js'.
> [/source/SampleWebApp/SampleWebApp.csproj]
>
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.426/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(147,5):
> warning MSB3026: Could not copy
> "/source/SampleWebApp/wwwroot/lib/jQuery/src/core/isAttached.js" to
> "/app/wwwroot/lib/jQuery/src/core/isAttached.js". Beginning retry 1 in
> 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path
> '/app/wwwroot/lib/jQuery/src/core/isAttached.js'.
> [/source/SampleWebApp/SampleWebApp.csproj]
>
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.426/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(147,5):
> warning MSB3026: Could not copy
> "/source/SampleWebApp/wwwroot/lib/jQuery/src/core/parseXML.js" to
> "/app/wwwroot/lib/jQuery/src/core/parseXML.js". Beginning retry 1 in
> 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path
> '/app/wwwroot/lib/jQuery/src/core/parseXML.js'.
> [/source/SampleWebApp/SampleWebApp.csproj]

I have certain files in my folder at the same level of wwwroot like

```
bundleconfig.json
libman.json
package-lock.json
bower.json
.bowerrc
```

I am not sure if these files are making any difference. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If the answer below not useful, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please create `/app/wwwroot/lib/jQuery` folder before trying to copy the files. You can try adding a line to you Dockfile.

```
RUN mkdir -p /app/wwwroot/lib/jQuery
```

If you still facing the issue, please share the dockfile for us.